# NullPointerException getApplicationThread()

Tags: android

I am trying to open a new intent from my HttpClient class but I get a getApplicationThread() error. I'm not sure what does mean and how to solve this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Context appContext;
    private HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        appContext = getApplicationContext();

        HttpClient.buildClient();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return appContext;
    }
```

public class HttpClient extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Call<Post> call = jsonApi.getPosts(GlobalConstants.template, GlobalConstants.Device_id, "NL", 4, 1);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() == false){
                    //todo
                    return;
                }

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.getAppContext(), QuestionActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
```

Comment: why don't you use an interface ?

Comment: in which line you get that error?

Comment: you can use a listener in your particular activity to listen from the API call at HttpClient

Comment: @JyotishBiswas line 95, at startActivity(i);

Comment: @Sana is there any examples on this?

Comment: Let me provide at answer section

Comment: Added the answer please check if it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please replace **getAppContext** to **this** and that will solve your error and then use listener to call new Activity as a best pratice.

Implement the interface from MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, ActivityIntentListener
```

Declare a variable for the listener or Interface you are calling,

```
private ActivityIntentListener listener;
```

And initialize the listener at constructor of the MainActivity like,

```
listener = this;
```

Just call the abstract method by the listener at api call response like the following,

```
Call<Post> call = jsonApi.getPosts(GlobalConstants.template, GlobalConstants.Device_id, "NL", 4, 1);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() == false){
                //todo
                return;
            }

listener.launchActivity();
        }
```

Now call the QuestionActivity in the launchActivity Mehtod,

```
@Override
   
public void launchActivity(){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
    }
```

The interface will be like this,

```
public Interface ActivityIntentListener {
 void launchActivity();
}
```

Comment: The 'public Interface ActivityIntentListener' does not like it when i put  the launchActivity code in there.

Comment: I will give it as a edition.There will be return type for the abstract method in the interface

Comment: the 3rd part of code you put up does not excist in the mainActivity, its from HttpClient class, so do i just make the private ActivityIntentListener listener; static so i can use it in the HttpClient class?

Answer (score 2):

The problems is these two parts:

> ```
> HttpClient extends AppCompatActivity
> ```

and

> ```
> private HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient()
> ```

You should never instantiate an activity class yourself. It won't be good for anything you'd want an activity for. For example, to have the activity thread set up for message processing.

First, HttpClient should not be an activity.

Then, one way to do an action when your network request completes is to have a callback as in @Sana's answer.